# Rewriting a curl as an HTTP POST Request to get access token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, curl, post, okta

I am attempting to get an access token by using a post request in rails.  I am able to write this request as a curl, successfully retrieving the token but when I try to convert it to rails, I get a 400 error.

The curl that works is as follows.

```
curl -v -X POST   --url https://subdomain.okta.com/oauth2/v1/token   --header 'accept: application/json'   --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'   --data 'grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Foauth%2Fobfuscated%2Fcallback1&code=HxYy0kiN-eG1GuZ3LaYA&client_id=somecode&client_secret=anothercode'
```

My ruby method that produces the 400 error is as follows:

```
theURLToGetToken = "https://subdomain.okta.com/oauth2/v1/token";
puts "URL for Token Validation"
puts theURLToGetToken

params = {
        'client_id' => AUTH['OKTA_CLIENT_ID'],
        'client_secret' => AUTH['OKTA_CLIENT_SECRET'],
        'code' => theCode,
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
        'redirect_uri' => "https://example.com/oath/obfuscated/callback1"
}

uri = URI.parse(theURLToGetToken)

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
request["content_type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
request["Accept"] = "application/json"
request.set_form_data(params)

req_options = {
    use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
    http.request(request)
end

puts "Here's the response"
pp response
```

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the issue here, but what I do in such cases is:

1) find a dummy website which you can use for the testing request (or create [requestbin](https://requestbin.fullcontact.com/))

2) send the request with curl to your website and save information about it

3) send the request using your code to your website

4) compare results

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You better use Postman which can be downloaded from here 
https://www.getpostman.com/pricing

Only after you confirmed the api properly with Postman, you better use rest-client, faraday or some neat api client.